# Using Windows COM Automation with Rust

Tags: windows, rust, com, ole

We're using a Brother label printer (QL-series) via its programming interface/SDK called 'bPac'. The tool, of which the label printing facility is part, is currently being rewritten from Ruby to Rust. During this process, I got stuck on the Win32/COM/OLE thing in Rust. A minimal working example in Ruby would be simple enough:

```rb
doc = WIN32OLE.new "bpac.Document"
doc.open 'some_label.lbx'
doc.SetPrinter "Brother QL-810W", true

print_opts = 0
doc.StartPrint("", print_opts)
doc.PrintOut(1, print_opts)
doc.EndPrint
```

I'd like to have a similar simple working example in Rust to start off with. As I'm not familiar with the Windows API the `windows-rs` crate is quite overwhelming. I figured, that I probably need the `System::Com` part from it. Here's what I started off with:

```rust
use windows::Win32::System::{Com, Ole};
use ::windows::core::Result;

pub fn print() {
    unsafe { Com::CoInitializeEx(std::ptr::null(), Com::COINIT_APARTMENTTHREADED) }.unwrap();

    let clsid = unsafe { Com::CLSIDFromProgID("bpac.Document") };
    println!("We've got a CLSID: {:?}", clsid);

    let obj: Result<Com::IDispatch> = unsafe { Com::CoCreateInstance(&clsid.unwrap(), None, Com::CLSCTX_ALL) };
    println!("IDispatch: {:?}", obj);
}
```

This way I can acquire an `IDispatch` object, which I should be able to query for available methods and properties. Having trouble calling into this low-level (very close to the C-metal) API. I found [win-idispatch](https://gitlab.com/phillipcouto/win-idispatch) crate, but that does not seem to play ball with `windows-rs`... :-/

Comment: I cannot help directly with your issue, but I would try to translate first the Ruby code to C, and then the C to Rust. The first will avoid any windows-rs or Rust specific issue and would be centered on understanding the OLE API. The second should be more or less straightforward.

Comment: Not sure about this bpac API but it's probably based on COM Automation which is an extra layer above COM (uses VARIANT, BSTR, IDispatch, late-binding, etc.) and was meant precisely to ease higher level languages access (VB, VBA, VBScript, scripting, or more recently python, etc.). The counter part is it's much more difficult and tedious for native access, eg: C/C++ or what you're heading to with Rust. These higher level languages contains lots of code to support this seamlessly. Here is some sample in C++ https://gist.github.com/Alexhuszagh/c231052cb6e51868215608305fe4e797

Comment: "Class not registered" has two simple explanations.  Either the component is not installed.  Or the program runs in 64-bit mode and the component is only installed for 32-bit programs.  The download page [specifically warns](https://support.brother.com/g/s/es/dev/en/bpac/download/index.html?c=eu_ot&lang=en&navi=offall&comple=on&redirect=on) about the latter case.

Comment: @SimonMourier thanks.. "COM Automation" seems to be the right term in the very ambiguous COM/OLE Windows nomenclature. Put me on track to try the `IDispatch` type (see edit), which is happily returned by `windows-rs`. Now still to find out how to call into this sucker...

Answer (score 3):

I wanted to do something similar: COM Office/Excel Automation using Rust.
In a nutshell I've built a wrapper around `IDispatch::GetIDsOfNames()` and `IDispatch::Invoke()` and for arguments one would use `VARIANT`.

The following resources helped me build a solution:
https://stuncloud.wordpress.com/2021/08/17/rust_com/
https://qiita.com/benki/items/42099c58e07b16293609
https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/previous-versions/office/troubleshoot/office-developer/automate-excel-from-c

Edit 2024-03-19: Add a quick-and-dirty example:

Cargo.toml

```ini
[package]
name = "office_interop"
version = "0.1.0"
edition = "2021"

# See more keys and their definitions at https://doc.rust-lang.org/cargo/reference/manifest.html

[dependencies]
anyhow = "1.0.81"

[dependencies.windows]
version = "0.54.0"
features = [
    "Win32_Foundation",
    "Win32_System_Com",
    "Win32_System_Ole",
]
```

main.rs

```rust
use anyhow::{anyhow, Context};
use std::time::Duration;
use std::{env, thread};
use windows::core::*;
use windows::Win32::System::Com::*;
use windows::Win32::System::Ole::*;

const LOCALE_USER_DEFAULT: u32 = 0x0400;
const LOCALE_SYSTEM_DEFAULT: u32 = 0x0800;

//cargo run -- FILE

fn main() -> anyhow::Result<()> {
    let mut args = env::args();
    let _ = args.next();
    let file = args.next();
    let file = file.ok_or(anyhow!("arg1 missing"))?;
    unsafe {
        let res = CoInitialize(None);
        if res.is_err() {
            return Err(anyhow!("error: {}", res.message()));
        }
        let _com = DeferCoUninitialize;

        let clsid = CLSIDFromProgID(PCWSTR::from_raw(
            HSTRING::from("Excel.Application").as_ptr(),
        ))
        .with_context(|| "CLSIDFromProgID")?;

        println!("{:?}", clsid);

        let excel = CoCreateInstance(&clsid, None, CLSCTX_LOCAL_SERVER)
            .with_context(|| "CoCreateInstance")?;
        let excel = IDispatchWrapper(excel);
        let _excel = DeferExcelQuit(&excel);

        excel
            .put("Visible", vec![false.into()])
            .with_context(|| "Visible false")?;

        excel
            .put("DisplayAlerts", vec![false.into()])
            .with_context(|| "DisplayAlerts false")?;

        let result = excel.get("Workbooks").with_context(|| "get Workbooks")?;
        let workbooks = result.idispatch().with_context(|| "idispatch Workbooks")?;

        let result = workbooks
            .call("Open", vec![(&file).into()])
            .with_context(|| format!("Failed to open file \"{}\"!", file))?;

        let workbook = result.idispatch().with_context(|| "idispatch Workbook")?;

        thread::sleep(Duration::from_millis(3000));

        let result = excel.get("Caption").with_context(|| "get Caption")?;
        println!("{}", result.string().with_context(|| "Caption string")?);

        workbook
            .call("Close", vec![false.into()])
            .with_context(|| "call Close")?;

        thread::sleep(Duration::from_millis(3000));

        let result = excel.get("Caption").with_context(|| "get Caption")?;
        println!("{}", result.string().with_context(|| "Caption string")?);

        thread::sleep(Duration::from_millis(3000));

        Ok(())
    }
}

pub struct Variant(VARIANT);

impl From<bool> for Variant {
    fn from(value: bool) -> Self {
        Self(value.into())
    }
}

impl From<i32> for Variant {
    fn from(value: i32) -> Self {
        Self(value.into())
    }
}

impl From<&str> for Variant {
    fn from(value: &str) -> Self {
        Self(BSTR::from(value).into())
    }
}

impl From<&String> for Variant {
    fn from(value: &String) -> Self {
        Self(BSTR::from(value).into())
    }
}

impl Variant {
    pub fn bool(&self) -> anyhow::Result<bool> {
        Ok(bool::try_from(&self.0)?)
    }

    pub fn int(&self) -> anyhow::Result<i32> {
        Ok(i32::try_from(&self.0)?)
    }

    pub fn string(&self) -> anyhow::Result<String> {
        Ok(BSTR::try_from(&self.0)?.to_string())
    }

    pub fn idispatch(&self) -> anyhow::Result<IDispatchWrapper> {
        Ok(IDispatchWrapper(IDispatch::try_from(&self.0)?))
    }

    pub fn vt(&self) -> u16 {
        unsafe { self.0.as_raw().Anonymous.Anonymous.vt }
    }
}

pub struct IDispatchWrapper(pub IDispatch);

impl IDispatchWrapper {
    pub fn invoke(
        &self,
        flags: DISPATCH_FLAGS,
        name: &str,
        mut args: Vec<Variant>,
    ) -> anyhow::Result<Variant> {
        unsafe {
            let mut dispid = 0;
            self.0
                .GetIDsOfNames(
                    &GUID::default(),
                    &PCWSTR::from_raw(HSTRING::from(name).as_ptr()),
                    1,
                    LOCALE_USER_DEFAULT,
                    &mut dispid,
                )
                .with_context(|| "GetIDsOfNames")?;

            let mut dp = DISPPARAMS::default();
            let mut dispid_named = DISPID_PROPERTYPUT;

            if !args.is_empty() {
                args.reverse();
                dp.cArgs = args.len() as u32;
                dp.rgvarg = args.as_mut_ptr() as *mut VARIANT;

                // Handle special-case for property-puts!
                if (flags & DISPATCH_PROPERTYPUT) != DISPATCH_FLAGS(0) {
                    dp.cNamedArgs = 1;
                    dp.rgdispidNamedArgs = &mut dispid_named;
                }
            }

            let mut result = VARIANT::default();
            self.0
                .Invoke(
                    dispid,
                    &GUID::default(),
                    LOCALE_SYSTEM_DEFAULT,
                    flags,
                    &dp,
                    Some(&mut result),
                    None,
                    None,
                )
                .with_context(|| "Invoke")?;

            Ok(Variant(result))
        }
    }

    pub fn get(&self, name: &str) -> anyhow::Result<Variant> {
        self.invoke(DISPATCH_PROPERTYGET, name, vec![])
    }

    pub fn int(&self, name: &str) -> anyhow::Result<i32> {
        let result = self.get(name)?;
        result.int()
    }

    pub fn bool(&self, name: &str) -> anyhow::Result<bool> {
        let result = self.get(name)?;
        result.bool()
    }

    pub fn string(&self, name: &str) -> anyhow::Result<String> {
        let result = self.get(name)?;
        result.string()
    }

    pub fn put(&self, name: &str, args: Vec<Variant>) -> anyhow::Result<Variant> {
        self.invoke(DISPATCH_PROPERTYPUT, name, args)
    }

    pub fn call(&self, name: &str, args: Vec<Variant>) -> anyhow::Result<Variant> {
        self.invoke(DISPATCH_METHOD, name, args)
    }
}

pub struct DeferExcelQuit<'a>(pub &'a IDispatchWrapper);

impl Drop for DeferExcelQuit<'_> {
    fn drop(&mut self) {
        let result = self.0.get("Workbooks").unwrap();
        let workbooks = result.idispatch().unwrap();
        let count = workbooks.int("Count").unwrap();
        for i in 1..=count {
            let result = workbooks
                .invoke(DISPATCH_PROPERTYGET, "Item", vec![i.into()])
                .unwrap();
            let workbook = result.idispatch().unwrap();
            workbook.put("Saved", vec![true.into()]).unwrap();
        }
        self.0.call("Quit", vec![]).unwrap(); //todo: quit doesn't kill process after open and Visible=true
    }
}

pub struct DeferCoUninitialize;

impl Drop for DeferCoUninitialize {
    fn drop(&mut self) {
        unsafe {
            CoUninitialize();
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: the links posted are in Chinese... care to show a sample example of updating a cell value in excel via rust COM interface?